# Rotating Matrix

Tags: java, math, matrix

I have a **matrixA** like that

```
[0][1]
[2][3]
[4][5]
```

And after my custom rotation (different numbering) becomes **matrixB** like this:

```
[0][1][2]
[3][4][5]
```

What i want is to map the numberings of the matrix A to B when i look the matrixA from the left->right.
To explain: **matrixA** looking from the left->right looks like this.

```
[1][3][5]
[0][2][4]
```

And **matrixB** is as it is

```
[0][1][2]
[3][4][5]
```

So i want to map, preferably with an equation these values

```
1->0
3->1
5->2
0->3
2->4
4->5
```

The real matrix is much larger so please don't focus to the size of this matrix

If anyone has any suggestions to find an equation for this mappings or some other way to do the mapping described? i would appreciate it

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Comment: edited to be more specific. Need an equation , matrix operation anything to do these value mappings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int height = 2, width = 3;  // of matrix B
int [][] a = {{0,1}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}};
int [][] b = {{0,1,2}, {3,4,5}};
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j) {
        int b_val = b[i][j];
        int a_val = a[j][height - i - 1];
        map.put(a_val, b_val);
    }
}

Set<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> entries = map.entrySet();
Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> it = entries.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> e = it.next();
    System.out.println(e.getKey() + " -> " + e.getValue());
}
```

See [here in action](http://www.ideone.com/ZipSg).

Answer (score 3):

Here is some code I use sometimes. This rotates the matrix by 90 or -90 degrees. This might be a start for your problem:

```
public int[][] rotateMatrixRight(int[][] matrix)
{
    /* W and H are already swapped */
    int w = matrix.length;
    int h = matrix[0].length;
    int[][] ret = new int[h][w];
    for (int i = 0; i < h; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < w; ++j) {
            ret[i][j] = matrix[w - j - 1][i];
        }
    }
    return ret;
}


public int[][] rotateMatrixLeft(int[][] matrix)
{
    /* W and H are already swapped */
    int w = matrix.length;
    int h = matrix[0].length;   
    int[][] ret = new int[h][w];
    for (int i = 0; i < h; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < w; ++j) {
            ret[i][j] = matrix[j][h - i - 1];
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://oeis.org/search?q=3%2C0%2C4%2C1%2C5%2C2&language=english&go=Search) you can find ten different formulas for your sequence `3,0,4,1,5,2`.

Always consult [OEIS](http://oeis.org/) when you need an integer sequence!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
map(matrixA,x,y)
  w=width of matrix A
  h=height of matrix A
  n=y*w+x
  from=matrixA(x,y)
  to=matrixA(n mod h, n / h)
  return (from, to)
```

To make a map, just iterate over all x and y and make a mapping of all those variables.

Comment: the tactic i used but Jiri gave a complete answer

Answer (score 0):

in place C solution follows

```
void rotateRight(int matrix[][SIZE], int length) {

    int layer = 0;

    for (int layer = 0; layer < length / 2; ++layer) {

        int first = layer;
        int last = length - 1 - layer;

        for (int i = first; i < last; ++i) {

            int topline = matrix[first][i];
            int rightcol = matrix[i][last];
            int bottomline = matrix[last][length - layer - 1 - i];
            int leftcol = matrix[length - layer - 1 - i][first];

            matrix[first][i] = leftcol;
            matrix[i][last] = topline;
            matrix[last][length - layer - 1 - i] = rightcol;
            matrix[length - layer - 1 - i][first] = bottomline;
        }
    }
}
```